# How to get a list of all Reflux actions names and a preEmit hook for all of them?

Tags: refluxjs

I know using `Reflux.__keep.createdActions` I get a list of all actions created. Is there a way to know the name of these actions?

Is there a way to define a `preEmit` hook for all actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important Note:** `Reflux.__keep` was actually originally created to support another feature that never materialized. However it was also creating memory leaks in some programs. Therefore it was recently made to NOT store anything by default. To make it store anything you have to use `Reflux.__keep.useKeep()` in latest versions of `reflux` and `reflux-core`. `Reflux.__keep` is not a documented part of the API, and as such changes to it do not necessarily follow semantic versioning. From v5.0.2 of Reflux onward the `useKeep()` is needed for `Reflux.__keep` to store anything.

On to the question though:

---

**1)** In `Reflux.__keep` there is a `createdActions` property, which is an Array holding all created actions so far (if you did the `useKeep()` thing, of course). Every action should have on it an `actionName` property telling you that action's name which you supplied when you created it:

```js
Reflux.__keep.useKeep()

Reflux.createActions(['firstAction', 'secondAction']);

console.log(Reflux.__keep.createdActions[0].actionName) // <-- firstAction
console.log(Reflux.__keep.createdActions[1].actionName) // <-- secondAction
```

**2)** `preEmit` hooks can be assigned to actions after-the-fact, so assigning them to actions within `Reflux.__keep.createdActions` would be a simple matter of a loop:

```js
Reflux.__keep.useKeep()

var Actions = Reflux.createActions(['firstAction', 'secondAction']);

var total = Reflux.__keep.createdActions.length;

for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
    Reflux.__keep.createdActions[i].preEmit = function(arg) { console.log(arg); };
}

Actions.firstAction('Hello');   // <- preEmit outputs "Hello"
Actions.secondAction('World!'); // <- preEmit outputs "World!"
```